# Query that's called by JS is being inserted twice

Tags: php, mysqli

First off, I've read other SO articles regarding queries inserting twice and the advice that is given is to make sure you don't have extra/unnecessary `mysqli_query()` functions on that page. I have done this but I still have this problem so I'm asking for myself.

I've been trying to figure out why the queries on liked_button.php are entering twice for about 24 hrs now with no luck.

I have a liked button that users can click, when that button is clicked, info goes to liked_button.php, that info is subsequently transferred to the `likes` and `notifications` table. But for some reason, the query runs twice.

The relevant code is below

My echoed like form with like button on index.php:

```
<form name='likes_form' id='likes_form' action='liked_button.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='hidden_folder' class='hidden_folder' value='$random_directory'>
<input type='hidden' name='hidden_name' class='hidden_name' value='$image_name'>
<input type='hidden' name='hidden_image' class='hidden_image' value='$image_info'>
<input type='hidden' name='hidden_user' class='hidden_user' value='$posted_by'>
<input type='image' id='like_button' class='like_button button' src='$button_source' onClick='return getLikes ()'>
<input disabled class='total_likes' value='$liked_count'>
</form>
```

The JS function that clicking the like button calls:

```
<script>
function getLikes()  {//function to leave_comment.php
var form = jQuery("#likes_form");      
$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: form.attr("action"), data: form.serialize(), success: function() {/**/} });
}
</script>
```

The liked_button.php page:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
header('location:errors/must_login.php');
}
$full_location = $_GET['hidden_image'];
$ghost_folder = $_GET['hidden_folder'];
$ghost_name = $_GET['hidden_name'];
$uploading_user = $_GET['hidden_user'];
$liker = $_SESSION['id'];
$date = date('M/d/Y');
$time = date('Y:m:d h:i:s');
$action = 'liked';
$status = '0';
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No SQLI");           
mysqli_select_db($conn, "sample") or die ("No DB");
$enter_likes = ("INSERT INTO `likes` (action, hidden_folder, hidden_name, liked_img_loc, liked_by, posted_by, liked_unliked, date, time, status) VALUES ('$action','$ghost_folder','$ghost_name','$full_location','$liker','$uploading_user','1','$date','$time','$status')");
mysqli_query($conn, $enter_likes) or die ("No query");  
$likes_notifications = ("INSERT INTO `notifications` (action, loc_of_img, causing_user, effected_user, time, date) VALUES ('$action','$full_location','$liker','$uploading_user','$time','$date')");
mysqli_query($conn, $likes_notifications) or die ("No notifications query");
mysqli_close($conn);
header('location:index.php');
?>
```

I've ran `var_dump()` on all variables on liked_button.php and all the variables contain the correct info.

For the life of me I just can't figure out why the queries are running twice.

I have the same sort of setup to get user comments and store them into `comments` and `notifications` tables, and that setup works just fine. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you check your browser's console (e.g. firebug net tab) to see how many requests are coming from the JS code? If your JS code is sending two ajax request, then it's not PHP's fault that it's doing two inserts - it's doing exactly what you're telling it to. And beyond that, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d

Comment: I am aware of the benefits of prepared statements. The question doesn't pertain to using prepared statements, rather two queries being inserting. Thanks for the comment though, I'll check on it.

Answer (score 0):

More then not this is a JS/jquery thing. Like Marc said, look in your firebug and check to see if there is one or two posts.

When this happens to me it is usually the .bind() function to me. I don't know how you trigger it cause I don't see the trigger anywhere. But that would a good place to start as any.

In short, check your firebug. If you dont have it (get it! Or), alert on success (or error if it fails for some reason).

Comment: so any idea why that particular JS function would be called twice, when it's the exact same syntax as the other functions, which are working fine?

Comment: If you are saying that, it means you checked firebug and confirmed that you have a second post right? If so, if you do a bind upon a bind (which does happen and unfortunately works) it will be called twice (and one more after every bind). Like I said, it sometimes happens to me, so it's some experience you might find useful. But for me to be useful to you in a more particular manner I would need some more data. Is your site localhost or might it be online? Cause than I can see for you

Comment: Hey Matt, I went back and changed the input from an image to a submit button (thus eliminating the need for JS) and now everything works great. So yea the problem was with my JS

Comment: Good! Now find that f***** and destroy it 007 style. ;)